# Calling Vowpal Wabbit from PHP?

Tags: php, c++, vowpalwabbit

I am trying to call Vowpal Wabbit and return the results to a php script and to a webpage;

```
$output = shell_exec('vw -i /root/house.model -t /root/house_dataset -p /dev/stdout --quiet');
```

When I echo the output:

```
echo $output;
```

It is empty, although when I run the script in the terminal it runs perfectly.

```
0.000018
0.282964
0.999793 second_house
0.282964
0.000128 third_house
```

When I do a var_dump on the $output in the php file, it returns NULL

Comment: Does the path to vw is correct? Is it added to PATH environment variable?

Comment: Yes it is. vw -i /root/house.model -t /root/house_dataset -p /dev/stdout --quiet runs in the terminal as is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to redirect standart output by adding `2>&1` at the end of the command.

```
shell_exec('vw -i /root/house.model -t /root/house_dataset -p /dev/stdout --quiet 2>&1')
```

Comment: Cool, I'm nearly there, now I just get permission denied. Thanks.

Comment: Is your web user (whatever php runs under) allowed to read from both files `/root/house.model` and `/root/house_dataset` ?